# Display next database entry

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am programming my first android app.
I am trying to create a quiz app. I have questions stored in a SQLite Database, which are displayed one after the other.
The user selects one of the answers (a radio button) and the clicks the 'next button' and the next question is displayed and so on.
Following code shows my Activity file displaying each question one after the other, which was **working perfectly**.

---

**ACEActivity** (old, working version)

```
public class ACEActivity extends Activity {
List<Question> quesList;
int score = 0;
int qid = 0;
Question currentQ;
TextView txtQuestion;
RadioButton rda, rdb, rdc, rdd;
Button butNext;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);

    DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(this);

    quesList = db.getAllACEQuestions();
    currentQ = quesList.get(qid);
    txtQuestion = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    rda = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio0);
    rdb = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio1);
    rdc = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio2);
    rdd = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio3);
    butNext = (Button)findViewById(R.id.nextButton);
    setQuestionView();

    butNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            RadioGroup grp = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
            RadioButton answer = (RadioButton)findViewById(grp.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
            Log.d("yourans", currentQ.getANSWER() + " " + answer.getText());
            // If the correct answer was clicked display the next question
            if(currentQ.getANSWER().equals(answer.getText())) {
                currentQ = quesList.get(qid);
                setQuestionView();
            }
        }
    });
}

// Load the next question
private void setQuestionView() {
    txtQuestion.setText(currentQ.getQUESTION());
    rda.setText(currentQ.getOPTA());
    rdb.setText(currentQ.getOPTB());
    rdc.setText(currentQ.getOPTC());
    rdd.setText(currentQ.getOPTD());
    qid++;
    }
}
```

---

In my newer version of this activity I load another activity  to give the user immediate feedback, if the correct or wrong answer was clicked.
**After displaying the feedback activity I would like to return to this activity and display the next question.


I am trying to do this by passing the question id from the feedback activity (ACECorrectActivity) to this activity (ACEActivity) without any success.**

---

**How I tried to solve this problem:**
**ACEActivity** (new version, just working for the first question)

```
public class ACEActivity extends Activity {
List<Question> quesList;
int score = 0;
int qid = 0;
Question currentQ;
TextView txtQuestion;
RadioButton rda, rdb, rdc, rdd;
Button checkBtn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);

    // THIS PART IS NEW ================================
    // Get the intent
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    // Get the question id (if there are any extras)
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        int qid = extras.getInt("nextQuestionID");
    } else {
        int qid = 0;
    }
    // ==================================================

    DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(this);

    quesList = db.getAllACEQuestions();
    currentQ = quesList.get(qid);
    txtQuestion = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    rda = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio0);
    rdb = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio1);
    rdc = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio2);
    rdd = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio3);
    checkBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.checkButton);

    setQuestionView(qid);

    checkBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            RadioGroup grp = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
            RadioButton answer = (RadioButton) findViewById(grp.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
            Log.d("yourans", currentQ.getANSWER() + " " + answer.getText());
            // THIS PART IS NEW AND WORKING FINE ================================
            // If the correct answer was clicked
            if (currentQ.getANSWER().equals(answer.getText())) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(ACEActivity.this, CorrectACEActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            // If the wrong answer was clicked
            } else {
                Intent intent = new Intent(ACEActivity.this, FalseACEActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    });
}

private void setQuestionView() {
    txtQuestion.setText(currentQ.getQUESTION());
    rda.setText(currentQ.getOPTA());
    rdb.setText(currentQ.getOPTB());
    rdc.setText(currentQ.getOPTC());
    rdd.setText(currentQ.getOPTD());
    qid++;
    }
}
```

**ACECorrectActivity** (feedback activity loaded, when the correct answer is chosen and the next button is clicked in the ACEActivity)

```
public class CorrectACEActivity extends Activity {
List<Question> quesList;
int score = 0;
int qid = 0;
Question currentQ;
TextView txtQuestion;
RadioButton rda, rdb, rdc, rdd;
Button nextBtn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_correct);

    DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(this);

    quesList = db.getAllACEQuestions();
    currentQ = quesList.get(qid);
    txtQuestion = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    rda = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio0);
    rdb = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio1);
    rdc = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio2);
    rdd = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio3);
    nextBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nextButton);

    // Set colors according to correct answer
    rda.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    rdb.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    rdc.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    rdd.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

    if(currentQ.getANSWER().equals(currentQ.getOPTA())) {
        rda.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
    } else if(currentQ.getANSWER().equals(currentQ.getOPTB())) {
        rdb.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
    } else if(currentQ.getANSWER().equals(currentQ.getOPTC())) {
        rdc.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
    } else if(currentQ.getANSWER().equals(currentQ.getOPTD())) {
        rdd.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
    }

    setQuestionView();

    // WHEN NEXT BUTTON IS CLICKED RETURN TO ACEActivity AND LOAD NEXT QUESTION
    nextBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(CorrectACEActivity.this, ACEActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("nextQuestionID", currentQ + 1);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

private void setQuestionView() {
    txtQuestion.setText(currentQ.getQUESTION());
    rda.setText(currentQ.getOPTA());
    rdb.setText(currentQ.getOPTB());
    rdc.setText(currentQ.getOPTC());
    rdd.setText(currentQ.getOPTD());
    qid++;
    }
}
```

---

**The first question works perfectly. However, as soon as I return to the ACEActivity after answering the first question, I am presented with the first question once again.**

---

As you can see, I am really new to this and would be tremendously happy for any kind of help! Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 intent.putExtra("nextQuestionID", currentQ + 1);
```

you are setting the extra wrong in CorrectACEActivity , shouldn't it be like this?

```
 intent.putExtra("nextQuestionID", qid+ 1);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! You are correct. There are a lot of other problems with my code as well. Therefore, I will try to completly alter the layout of my project. But thank you very much for pointing this out!